# laravel 5.7 intervention Image::make return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

When I upload an image for compress use Intervention, sometimes it shows me **500 Internal Server** Error.

The image size less then **1Mb**

This error usually occurs after I run `php artisan serve`and request compress API for the first time.

```
public function compressPhoto(Request $request)
{
        $photo = $request->photo;
        $file = Image::make($photo);
        return 'success';
}
```

Comment: What information do you have any information on `laravel.log`? You should have the cause logged there.

Comment: there are nothing in my log

Comment: Do you have the php-extensions installed? http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

Comment: Whenever there's a 500 server error, it means that there are errors in the server that are not handled. In Laravel, in most cases, it would be logged in your storage/logs/laravel.log. Try setting `APP_DEBUG` in your `.env.` to `true` to see detailed error in the response. Also set the `APP_LOG_LEVEL` to at least `error`.

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu I set .env=true in .env , and the log work for other issue, but nothing for this error

Comment: @Gudgip Yes, I already installed it.

Comment: Then maybe it's handled by the `nginx`/`apache` level.

Answer (score 0):

In a Laravel application, it is also possible to pass an uploaded file directly to the make a method. You must install it properly before using it: [intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

```
  Image::make(Input::file('photo'))->save('foo.jpg');
```

---

If your file size is more than 2MB then you have to increase it `upload_max_filesize =` in ***C:\xampp\php\php.ini*** file

Comment: I has installed intervention Image, and file size less then 2MB. It doesn't work. But still thanks for the answer~

Comment: @LouKao start by inspecting the Laravel logs **(storage/logs)** to see if there is more detailed information about the error there, please provide some more info then I can help you out

Comment: the problem is there are nothing in storage/logs, I set APP_DEBUG=true in the .env

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question might be not actual, but one of the possible solutions is to increase memory limit in your script

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

or set

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

in your php.ini file.